# How to run ios 4.3 app in ios 4.0

Tags: iphone-sdk-4.3

How to run application which is build using ios-sdk-4.3 in ios-sdk-4.0.I set build target but also am getting lots of crash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly but try following:

Assuming you are using XCode4, double click on your Project 
file to open your Project settings (that's the first Item in your Project Navigator).
Selecting the INFO Tab, choose your Deployment Target, for example 4.0.

I can't help you with the crashes but please try to use the debugger to find out which part of your application is causing the issues.

Let me know if that answers your question

Comment: Ya thats what i expect..here i set target but also am getting crash.i want to know what are the new features added in 4.3 when compare to 4.0.can u give a link to study the differentiations.

Comment: The [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) will take you to the iOS release notes. Did you try to re-install XCode ?

Comment: Thanks for that link..I also have one doubt that the app created using xcode 4 not running in lowest xcode version why.